# jQuery Slider empty second loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slider

I am implementing a simple image slider with navigation controls.

I have two problems though.

1. There are four slides, and the code creates four controls for each of the slides, it loops through the slides, however after the 4 slides it loops again without going through the slides.
2. I can't click on the individual buttons to direct me to the slides...

Could someone help a bro out.

```
function createNav() {
  var numofslides = sel.children().length;
  console.log(numofslides);

  //alert(countChildren);
  for (var i = 0; i < numofslides; i++) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="circle"></li>');
  }  
}

//Slide function......//
window.time = function() {
  now = setInterval(function() {
    sel.children().eq(0).fadeOut().next().fadeIn().end().appendTo(sel);
    el.children().eq(count).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    if (count == el.children().length) {
      el.children().eq(0).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
      count = 0;
    }
    count++
    //console.log(count);
  }, 2000);

};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6qqc9ohf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/6qqc9ohf/6/

I have fixed below issues:

1. While creating navigation you are appending `li`'s to both the `ul`'s. So change

   `$('ul').append('<li class="circle"></li>');`

   to

   `$('#container').append('<li class="circle"></li>');`

2. While creating navigation, make the first `li` as `active`. Add below code to `createNav()`.

   `$('#container li:eq(0)').addClass('active');`

3. Change count to 1. `var count = 1;`

Comment: Thanks! How could I make each circle clickable to corresponding slides please?